# How to export text value instead of foreign key id from mysql table to excel in django

Tags: mysql, django, excel

Good day everyone! I'am new to django and i want to learn a lot in this excellent framework. I want to learn in django-import-export application and I have trouble in exporting data from mysql table. Django-import-export application export foreign key id rather than the foreign key I specified in to_field.

Below is my model

```
from django.db import models


class Rank(models.Model):
    RankCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    RankDesc = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    OrderNo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.RankCode


class Status(models.Model):
    StatusCode = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Status'

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.StatusCode


class Student(models.Model):
    Rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, to_field='RankCode', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    Status = models.ForeignKey(Status, to_field='StatusCode', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.Rank
```

If I export Student model to excel, I want the output to be the value of specified foreign key in to_field and not the id.

Thanks in advance to those who can contribute.